# php MVC with javascript interaction

Tags: javascript, php, model-view-controller

Ok so I've build a little php MVC framework. It basically has the following layers:

- **controllers**: handling input, calling functions from the services based on that input and usually forwarding variables to the view (and rendering it)
- **domain-layer**: split up into...
- ...*models*: domain entities, basically just setters and getters validating data and providing a consistent
  data interface for the views
- ...*mappers*: loading/storing models
  from/to the database
- ...*services*: encapsulating domain logic, like
  "registerUser" or "sendMessage"
- **views**: basically just html with some php.

Ok so far this works well. However now I would like to add some javascript functionality. I'm not sure how to do this properly. I know I'm supposed to send post-requests to my php scripts, but my controllers f.e. are not providing any return values, but instead just output views. So if I wanted to retrieve a list of friends for a user with js, would I..

- a) provide a "javascript access service", which handles javascript requests with help from the domain services and outputs the results as json? What I wouldnt like about this, is that it leads to redundancy in some of my requests. I might have a regular controller action for viewFriends() and now I would have to add a javascriptService->viewFriends() as well.
- b) have all my controllers return results? I don't even think this is really possible, cause javascript can only store whats being echoed, right?

Whats the way to go here?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you define variable?
declare variable globaly.
give all function unique name.

Comment: @ChiragSenjaliya: Sorry, I don't really understand what you're saying..

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I'd consider what a view is, and then make some minor changes to your controllers to enable them to output views that are not just HTML - so for example you might want to output some JSON data - and this could be considered a view.

This tutorial - http://www.paulund.co.uk/use-php-to-detect-an-ajax-request shows how to check if a request is Ajax - so you could use this method in the controller to decide how you want to deliver a view etc.

Comment: Ok, thats a possibility, thanks. Would appreciate some more suggestions.